# because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: magento2

because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. "How do you solve it
[image]

My web server is nginxx,so pub/static  nothing".htaccess" file，

I have executed the following permission command and it is still not correct

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :nginx . 
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem with resource compilation.

Aside the folder permissions there are other factors that could lead at this point.

Are you in developer mode? The dev mode use a symlink strategy for passing the resource to the frontend. Maybe your sys admin blocked symlink for security reason.

If you are already in production mode, you can try to remove

```
generated 
var/view_preprocessed 
pub/static/
```

folders and execute a

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If you open the chosen.css file with an editor or via browser you can read the contents of the file which may indicate the error.